# Silent long overflow while implementing Fibonacci with Callables

Tags: java, long-integer, fibonacci, integer-overflow, callable

I am trying to implement the Fibonacci sequence using callables and seeded the initial values of my Fibonacci callable with 3,4,5,6 and 2000. The output I get is as follows:

> 3 5 8 13
>   -820905900187520670

The problem is when I am trying to calculate fib(2000) in my callable. Can somebody take a look at my code provided below to see where I am going wrong with my approach:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;

class FibonacciGen implements Callable<Long>{
    private Long fib;
    public FibonacciGen(long num){
        this.fib = num;
    }
    public Long call(){
        return calculateFibonacci(fib);
    }

    private long calculateFibonacci(long someNum){
        long firstNum = 0L;
        long secondNum = 1L;
        long counter = 0L;
        while(counter<someNum){
            long fibCalc = secondNum+firstNum;
            firstNum = secondNum;
            secondNum = fibCalc;
            counter= counter+1L;
        }
        return secondNum;
    }   

}

public class FibonacciCallable{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ArrayList<Callable<Long>> results = new ArrayList<Callable<Long>>();
        CompletionService<Long> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<Long>(exec);
        results.add(new FibonacciGen(3L));
        results.add(new FibonacciGen(4L));
        results.add(new FibonacciGen(5L));
        results.add(new FibonacciGen(6L));
        results.add(new FibonacciGen(2000L));
            try{
                for(Callable<Long> fs:results){
                    ecs.submit(fs);
                }
                System.out.println("Submitted all the tasks");
                int n = results.size();
                for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
                    System.out.println("Taking the first completed task");
                    Long r = ecs.take().get();
                    if(r != null)
                        System.out.println(r);
                    }   


            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){System.out.println(ex);return;}
            catch(ExecutionException e){System.out.println(e);}
            finally{exec.shutdown();}
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with it, `long` is simply far too small for f(2000).

Comment: you might overflow the buffer you should try using `BigInteger`

Comment: `f(2000) = 4.224696333392424 * 10^417` That ain't gonna fit in a `long`.

Comment: Calculating fibonacci numbers is a perfect example of when you shouldn't use multiple threads. ;) http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/why-concurency-examples-are-confusing.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey This is different though, each number is calculated in a single thread.

Comment: @biziclop and fib(n) will calculate all the previous fib(N) making all the prevous calculations repeated work.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's true, they should start with different initial values.

Comment: @biziclop Usually I start with `1` and `1` ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java doesn't throw an exception on overflow, just wraps the value around, that's why you're getting the strange result. Fibonacci is a fast growing sequence, the 2000. element is way beyond `long`

Try using `BigInteger`, it will give you arbitrary precision (at the cost of performance obviously).

Comment: If you want to keep using `long`, but want "noisy" overflows, try [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`LongMath.checkedAdd`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/math/LongMath.html#checkedAdd(long,%20long)).  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)